# Unit test case for angular directive to manipulate css

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, directive

```
angular.module('myApp').directive(errorDirective, function(){
return {

link: function(scope, element, attributes){
      element.bind('change paste keyup', function(){
      var value= $(this).val();
      if(value < 100)
         $('#inputerror').removeClass('dispnone').addClass('dispblock');
      else if(value >100 && value <500)
         $('#inputerror').removeClass('disp').addClass('dblock');
      else
      $('#inputerror').removeClass('dnone').addClass('displayblock');
      });
      }
}
});
```

in my html file

```
<input id= 'inputvalue' ng-model="inputvalue" errorDirective/>
<span id= 'inputerror' class="errorNone"><span>Error occurs </span></span>
```

How to write the unit test case for the given directive ??

Comment: You shouldn't be using a custome directive for this. The ng-class directive should be used here. 
`<input id= 'inputvalue' ng-model="inputvalue" ng-class="{dispnone: inputvalue<100, dblock: (inputvalue >= 100 && inputvalue < 500), dblock: inputvalue >= 500}"/>`

Comment: the class are added or removed for the span tag based on the input value not for input tag. So in that case will your suggestion work?

Comment: there are more logic in the directive